# distance_of_time_in_words gone crazy!

Tags: datetime, symfony1, helper, symfony-1.4

```
distance_of_time_in_words(strtotime(2010-08-07), strtotime(2010-08-01))
```

returns '6 minutes'

```
$a = '2010-08-02 00:39:29'
$b = '2010-08-01'
distance_of_time_in_words($a, $b)
```

returns 'less than a minute'

```
$a = '2010-08-02 00:39:29'
$b = '2010-08-01 20:08:00'
distance_of_time_in_words($a, $b)
```

returns 'less than a minute'

I wonder if I'm going wrong in the conversion.. Does it accept a timestamp or date?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// call
distance_of_time_in_words(getUnixTimestamp(), getUnixTimestamp($bill->created_at));

// utility method
public function getUnixTimestamp($datetime = null)
{
  return date("U", (($datetime) ? strtotime($datetime) : time()));
}
```

**Hope this will help others!**

Answer (score 2):

Checking it's [source code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/DateHelper.php#L68) it seems it needs timestamps (it does some calculations at the beginning of the function).